# Why is there an upper mass limit of $300$ GeV of the Higgs boson for $W/Z$ associated production and t$\bar{\mathrm{t}}$H associated production modes?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, radiation, feynman-diagrams, higgs

I am currently trying to understand this graph for the cross-section versus Higgs mass:

[image: Branching ratio graph]

As you can see from the above graph, there is an abrupt cut-off at $M_H=300$ GeV where I have put a green box around.

The (a), (b), (c) and (d) here all correspond to Feynman diagrams for 4 Higgs boson production modes as shown below:

[image: Higgs production modes]

My question is, why is there an abrupt stop to the lowest 3 lines corresponding to the associated production modes (c) and (d) whereas (a) and (b) can be produced for any Higgs mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing physical, as of course the cross section doesn't drop to zero beyond that point or anything. It's just not plotted on this specific graph.

Indeed, you can see the cross sections for these processes up to $400~\rm GeV$ [here](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LHCPhysics/CERNYellowReportPageAt7TeV2014). For instance, for ZH production it is $12.39~\rm fb$ at $300~\rm GeV$ and $3.357~\rm fb$ at $400~\rm GeV$. (Note, however, that the several digits given belie the very significant systematic uncertainties).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but why stop at $400$ GeV? Or, is it because the reason for stopping at $400$ GeV is because the 3 curves that I boxed in green would go below the horizontal axis and a negative cross-section is unphysical?

Comment: @BLAZE The plot is logarithmic- the bottom line corresponds to around $3~\rm fb$, not $0$. And there's no physical reason for it to stop at $400~\rm GeV$ either. But they have to stop *somewhere*. Calculating these cross sections is computationally expensive so there needs to be some reason for it to be worth calculating in the first place.